# document.getElementById("className").className Cannot set property 'className' of null

Tags: javascript, css, element

I'm trying to find an element with the class "active" and change its class to "inactive".

Currently I'm getting this error

```
Cannot set property 'className' of null
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("active").className = "inactive";
```

html:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="paginationlink active" data-page-number="1"></a>
```

I don't believe the issue is because I have two classes because I have tried removing the `paginationlink` from the element and I still return the same error.

I have looked at a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733660/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-classname-of-null) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777911/pagination-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-classname-of-null) but I do not have an Id attribute to pull from that would be unique.

Comment: the getElementById function will give you the DOM object having as id "active" meanwhile you're not having it you have a class active not an id

Comment: When you set `.className` it will replace *all* the classes. So you'll lose the `paginationlink` class. You should use `.classList.add('inactive')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're getting the element using `document.getElementById("active")` but there is not `id="active"` defined. Try adding an `id="active"`

Comment: It was my misunderstanding that .className somehow made it search by class name, rather than Id first. That worked and thank you!

Comment: he can not put id="active" so bootstrap will not recognize it it will work as a class

Comment: @Alkarin I'm glad it worked :)